# Getting the unique ID of a Viddler video from the embed code (regex/parse_url)

Tags: php, pattern-matching

Not working. I think I have looked at it too long and I'm blind to the problem:

```
<?php
$str = $_POST['data'];
$pattern = '#(www\.|https?:\/\/){?}[a-zA-Z0-9]{2,254}\.[a-zA-Z0-9]{2,4}(\S*)#i';
   if (preg_match_all($pattern, $str, $matches, PREG_PATTERN_ORDER)) {
    $uri = "($matches[1])";
   }
$path = parse_url($uri, PHP_URL_PATH);
$output = substr(strrchr($path, '/'), 1);
?>
```

Sample embed code - I need the a695c468 part of the URL - it may change in length:

`<iframe id="viddler-a695c468" src="//www.viddler.com/embed/a695c468/?f=1&offset=0&autoplay=0&secret=91361932&disablebranding=0&view_secret=91361932" width="545" height="349" frameborder="0" mozallowfullscreen="true" webkitallowfullscreen="true"></iframe>`

Answer (score 2):

Why parse it from URL? iframe id will be faster.
`preg_match_all('/"viddler-(\w+)"/', $str, $matches, PREG_PATTERN_ORDER);`

Updated:
Try this
`preg_match_all('/www\.viddler\.com\/embed\/(\w+)\//', $str, $matches, PREG_PATTERN_ORDER);`

Comment: In case someone only pastes the url into the form and not the entire embed code.

Comment: I'm doing something wrong - I'm getting "Array" instead of a695c468. I tried reading the parts of the array[0] no change.

Comment: Just dump your array with `var_dump($array_var);` and see where is your response.